# PHPWebDriver - Load JQuery dynamically then execute JavaScript when it is ready

Tags: javascript, php, selenium, webdriver, browserstack

I'm definitely a noob in Selenium, but I'm trying to figure out how to use BrowserStack Automate via php-webdriver to do automated testing on Web pages using their impressive array of browsers and devices.

What I'm trying to do is:

1. Load JQuery dynamically
2. Execute some JQuery-dependent JavaScript when JQuery is ready

Here is the code I have:

```
require "path/to/php-webdriver-master/lib/__init__.php";

    $web_driver = RemoteWebDriver::create(
        "http://myusername:mykey@hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub",
        array("browser" => "Firefox", "browser_version" => "31.0", "os" => "Windows", "os_version" => "7", "resolution" => "1024x768")
    );
    $web_driver->get("http://google.com/ncr");

    $load_jquery_str = 'file_ref_obj = document.createElement("script");file_ref_obj.src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js";file_ref_obj.type = "text/javascript";file_ref_obj.async = false;document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(file_ref_obj);';
    $exec_jquery_str = '$(function(){var test = $("#mngb").find("gb_f gb_h").attr("data-pid");alert(test);});';

    $web_driver->executeScript($load_jquery_str);
    sleep(5);
    $web_driver->executeScript($exec_jquery_str);

    $web_driver->quit();
```

It doesn't work and I get an error saying `$ is not defined`.

How can reconfigure this to work. Thanks.

Comment: does the error point to a particular line ?

Comment: @Dagon It does in the output, but it's not a PHP error: It just means that JQuery hasn't loaded yet, but I don't know how to sequence the script execution so that `$web_driver->executeScript($load_jquery_str)` loads JQuery **then** executes `$exec_jquery_str`.

Comment: @ObinwanneHill You should use Selenium API to find_element, click etc. to simulate user actions properly. execute_script can be used to set pre-requisites or for actions that aren't possible by normal selenium commands.